# Could I replace headphones NIMH battery with Lithium Ion phone battery of the same voltage?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, battery-operated, battery-chemistry, replacement

Is it possible to replace a battery for headphones? I would like to replace a 052030 li po battery with a Nokia BL-5C Lithium Ion battery. The li po battery is rated at **130 mAh with 3.7v**. The Lithium Ion battery, on the other hand, is **1 Ah with 3.7v**.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you do that, I'd expect some fire when you try to charge it.

Comment: Possible? Yes. Advisable? **No**. Li-Ion batteries need to be charged in a different way (much more careful) than NiMh batteries. Li-Ion batteries need a **special charging circuit designed for Li-Ion cells**. If you break that rule then you will probably **damage** the Li-Ion battery. {...} [Edited by a moderator to remove obsolete information.]

Comment: @abu-bakar You can do it, just adapt a new charger for your replacement.

Comment: The charging port is fixed in the circuit of headphones. So voltage provided to the battery must be fixed.i use general 2 ampere mobile charger to charge headphones. As you people said, NIMH needs different charger so maybe the circuit modifies the given voltage and current. When NIMH battery gets low, headphones show warning and then turn off. Same with the charging, it stops charging when battery is already full. Will it provides protection to the li ion battery after replacement?

Comment: Many links in google says that a 052030 battery is Li-PO, not Ni-MH.

Comment: Oh yeah really. Thank you guys. Should I do replacement without worry?

Comment: Yeah I read the answers. Actually I was wrong. Headphones battery is li po  not NIMH and I wanna replace it with li ion . Now the question is that can I replace li po with li ion?

Comment: Please edit your orginal question. It still says NiMH.

Comment: I'm confused now.  NiMH, Li-ion, or Li-ion polymer (LiPo).  Which of them?

Comment: Headphones has lithium polymer battery. I want to replace it with lithium ion battery. There is nothing to do with NIMH battery. It was just a mistake. @Oskar Skog

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Many links in Google say that a 052030 battery is a Li-PO, not a Ni-MH type. A li-Po is almost the same as a Lithium-Ion type but the huge battery will take a very long time to charge.

Comment: This does not answer OPs question.